# What is an equivalent Italian expression for "actions speak louder than words"?

Tags: translation

What is an equivalent Italian expression for the phrase "actions speak louder than words"? ([reference](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/actions_speak_louder_than_words)) This phrase is often used to in relation to someone's unfulfilled promises.

Example 1:

- A: *I'll come tonight.*
- B: *You said that last night, and the night before.  Actions speak louder than words.*

Example 2: *He has many great ideas, but what good are they?  Actions speak louder than words.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Italian you would say "Contano i fatti, non le parole" which would mean (literally translated) "The facts are the ones that count, not words".

Following the same example you mentioned:

- A: *Questa sera vengo, promesso*
- B: *L'hai detto anche la notte scorsa e quella prima ancora. Contano i fatti, non le parole*

Comment: How interesting and beautiful! A new contributor answers a new contributor. And both question and answer are of good quality. And both persons have the same reputation. I had never seen a situation like this before in entire StackExchange websites. Keep going ;-) Oh, by the way, I'm a new contributor myself with less reputation x-D